# How do you get WPF to work like Forms at design time?

Tags: wpf, controls, resize

A bit new with WPF...It seems like not matter what I change with horizontal and vertical alignment, WPF has a mind of its own when resizing my controls in design time.  I created a new Window, placed a couple of buttons and text boxes and whenever i change the size of the window all the controls get resized.  Is there a way to lock it down or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout you are using might be a Grid. Try replacing that with a ***Canvas*** and you will get the similar behavior as win forms design.

Suggestion: When we use WPF the adavantage we can get is the resizability and be able to dynamically arrange(Change) controls inside a layout etc.. So Try using dynamic layouts than static layouts like "Canvas"